# Execution message Oracle sqlplus from Unix

Tags: oracle, shell, unix, sqlplus

I have a process that connects to Oracle sqlplus from a shell that requests a password and then start the execution of Store Procedure in the following way:

```
echo -e "Enter Password"
read -s pass

$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -s -l /nolog << EOF >> $log_deploy
connect $schema/$pass@$db
@$sql/main.sql;
EOF
```

The fact is that this process has a variable duration and it is executed from the console of the server by an operator.

There is some way of notifying the operator every 10 minutes for example **"The process continues in execution"**? Since once inside the sqlplus remains in it until the execution of sp ends and returns to the console.

Any suggestions or idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put the sqlplus heredoc in background. Wait for completion of last background process id ($!) and `sleep` for some amount of seconds by checking its completion (10 mins is a long interval by the way )

```
intrvl=100
sqlplus  <<EOF &
input
EOF
PID=$!  #get the pid of the last background process.

while [ 1 ]
do
if ps -p $PID > /dev/null
 then
   echo "The process continues in execution"
   sleep $intrvl
 else 
   break
 fi
done
```

Having said that a good approach should be to keep the monitoring part out of the processing code.